# Bamboo api to get the recent build number for a specific branch

Tags: api, bamboo, bamboo-specs

I'm trying to get the latest build number from a specific branch. I'm able to do with the below api call. It get the build number whether the job is success or failed, but not if its ABORTED. can anyone let me know the api call to get the build number even if thats aborted?

api call - `curl https://bamboo.test.com/rest/api/latest/result/AVC-SFADR15?max-results=1`

Answer (score 0):

includeAllStates is the paramter you need

Use below command:

```
curl https://bamboo.test.com/rest/api/latest/result/AVC-SFADR15?max-results=1&includeAllStates
```